# Thoughts on removing ruby tags for questions about ruby-on-rails.

Tags: discussion

The current state of the ruby section is quite poor. Currently, almost every Ruby on Rails question also gets tagged with Ruby. The resulting Ruby section is essentially a duplicate of the Ruby on Rails sections with a few ruby-specific questions thrown in.  Should we start trying to separate these two by removing Ruby tags from Ruby on Rails posts?

Comment: You can always ignore the rails tag if you want to see [all ruby questions without rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby+-ruby-on-rails).

Comment: That's true. However, a lot of Rails questions are related to specific Rails libraries. I don't see the value in tagging these with Ruby. Also, I like answering Rails questions. I don't necessarily want to ignore it.

Comment: So you want to both see them and not see them.  Sorry, but there isn't going to be a way for you to do that.

Comment: All I want is the questions in the Ruby section to pertain to Ruby, not specific Rails libraries. I think this has value.

Comment: And I showed you exactly how to do that, to which you replied that you still want to be able to see Rails questions.

Comment: A bigger problem in my opinion is that many plain ruby questions get tagged ruby + ruby-on-rails. Every day I remove the rails tag from several pure ruby questions. Also the name "Ruby on rails" was reduced to only "Rails" many years ago, so the tag should be just rails.